# Invalid WKT from ST_GeometryFromText(x)

Tags: sql, gis, presto

I'm trying to convert varchar WKT format to geometry using presto function `ST_GeometryFromText` but I get this error

```
Error running query: Invalid WKT: 0101000020E6100000000000407BF43E40000000203CFA3D40
```

The point format in the database is stored in this format `0101000020E6100000000000407BF43E40000000203CFA3D40` as `varchar`, i just want to convert it to a geometry point, i used to use `ST_X` & `ST_Y` in `postgis` but after migrating to presto these two functions aren't supported.

Comment: `0101000020E6100000000000407BF43E40000000203CFA3D40` is not a valid geometry text. Have you tried `ST_GeomFromBinary`? You might need to convert your string to binary before using it though, using something like `from_hex`

Comment: I tried from_hx and got this error "Error running query: invalid shape type"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the answer is simply by removing this part of the string `'20E61000'`, once removed, the function works fine, I've used this function

```
ST_GEOMFROMBINARY(FROM_HEX(REPLACE('0101000020E6100000000000407BF43E40000000203CFA3D40', '20E61000')))
```

and it worked fine, also I've verified the answer using python Shapley wkb function.

Answer (score 1):

If you run

```
SELECT ST_AsText('0101000020E6100000000000407BF43E40000000203CFA3D40')
```

...in `postgis`, you will get the point `POINT(30.955005645752 29.9774799346924)`.

If you want to separate longitude and latitude, run:

```
SELECT ST_X(ST_AsText('0101000020E6100000000000407BF43E40000000203CFA3D40')), ST_Y(ST_AsText('0101000020E6100000000000407BF43E40000000203CFA3D40'))
```

Comment: yes, I used to use these functions when I was using postgis, but now i'm using presto and presto doesn't support all of these functions and not all formats, it only supports these functions https://prestodb.github.io/docs/current/functions/geospatial.html    but soemthing is wrong regarding the format, that's why it is not working, do you have any idea how to solve this issue?

Comment: Oh, I see. I am not familiar with presto, but ST_AsText looks to be one of the supported functions. Did the first query work?

Comment: And this might sound basic, but did you use brackets for your data ('0101000020E6100000000000407BF43E40000000203CFA3D40')? From the error message, it looks like they are missing.

Comment: The format above is actually HEXEWKB which presto does not support, but it is PostGis' canonical output unfortunately.
`select ST_AsHEXEWKB(ST_AsText('0101000020E6100000000000407BF43E40000000203CFA3D40'));`
The above should output the same as the input and show the format is HEXEWKB. 

I have not found a great way to convert this in Presto, but am looking into creating a UDF from [LocationTech's WKBReader](https://github.com/locationtech/jts/blob/master/modules/core/src/main/java/org/locationtech/jts/io/WKBReader.java#L160)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue...had to massage the heck out of this thing.

```
select ST_GeomFromBinary(from_hex(to_utf8(replace(geom,'20E61000')))) as geom from ...
```